# Inputs not showing up as required in browser for ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django

When I instantiate the following form and use it in my template. My inputs don't show up as required. Anyone have any idea why?

```
class SampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Making name required
    self.fields['x'].required = True
    self.fields['y'].required = True
    self.fields['z'].required = True
    self.fields['a'].required = True

  class Meta:
    model = Sample
    fields = ['x','y','z','a' 'email']
```

**Template**

```
<div>
  <form>
    {{form}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/474/

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
{% if field.field.required %}
```

using this snippet:
[snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/474/)

Comment: I need the input to be like this `<input required></input>`  in the browser and this is not happening.

Comment: <input {% if field.field.required %} required{%endif%}></input>